# Return many small data samples based on more than one column in SQL (BigQuery)

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

In this example, I have a book database, with one record per book. The records contain the book owners, the genre, and some other info. I need to return a sample of the top 20 per owner, per genre.

The way I was planning on doing it was to programatically build a huge query like:

```
(SELECT Owner, Genre, Data_one, Data_two FROM `dataset-table` WHERE Genre LIKE "%HORROR%" AND Owner LIKE "Alex" LIMIT 20)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT Owner, Genre, Data_one, Data_two FROM `dataset-table` WHERE Genre LIKE 
"%COMEDY%" AND Owner LIKE "Alex" LIMIT 20)
UNION ALL
(SELECT Owner, Genre, Data_one, Data_two FROM `dataset-table` WHERE Genre LIKE 
"%HORROR%" AND Name LIKE "Sarah" LIMIT 20)
UNION ALL
(SELECT Owner, Genre, Data_one, Data_two FROM `dataset-table` WHERE Genre LIKE 
"%COMEDY%" AND Owner LIKE "Sarah" LIMIT 20)
 UNION ALL
(SELECT Owner, Genre, Data_one, Data_two FROM `dataset-table` WHERE Genre LIKE 
"%HORROR%" AND Owner LIKE "James" LIMIT 20)
UNION ALL
(SELECT Owner, Genre, Data_one, Data_two FROM `dataset-table` WHERE Genre LIKE "%COMEDY%" AND Owner LIKE "James" LIMIT 20)
```

However, I need to this for a few hundred users and 6 genres at the same time, and I am getting an error in BigQuery saying that the query is too complex.

Does anyone know a way to return lots of limited samples based on more than one category? It's fine if they end up in one big dataset.

So for example:

```
    Owner       |       Genre       |       Data_one       |       Data_two
    Alex        |       Horror      |     Stephen King     |         IT
                  .... 100 more Horror books from Alex ....
    Sarah       |       Horror      |     Darren Shan      |      Lord Loss
                  .... 100 more Horror books from Sarah ....
    Alex        |       Comedy      |     Russel Brand     |        MBW
                  .... 100 more Comedy books from Alex ....
```

I would return any sample of 20 horror books from Alex, 20 Horror from Sarah, and then 20 Comedy from Alex.

Comment: please give us sample data for owner, name, genre, data_one and data_two and your expected result.

Comment: Done, and I actually mixed up Name and Owner in the original, they're the same field.

Comment: see the answer  - it does exactly this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below is example for BigQuery Standard SQL

it is using `bigquery-public-data.medicare.physicians_and_other_supplier_2012` public data and name, city, org are used to mimic your author, genre, data

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 
    nppes_provider_first_name name, 
    nppes_provider_city city, 
    nppes_provider_last_org_name org
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.medicare.physicians_and_other_supplier_2012`
), search AS (
  SELECT name, city FROM
  UNNEST(['JOHN','MICHAEL','DAVID','ROBERT']) name, 
  UNNEST(['NEW YORK','SPRINGFIELD','COLUMBUS','HOUSTON','DALLAS']) city
)
SELECT name, city, org FROM (
  SELECT name, city, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT org LIMIT 20) orgs
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  JOIN search USING(name, city)
  WHERE RAND() < 0.5
  GROUP BY name, city
), UNNEST(orgs) org
ORDER BY name, city, org
```

So for your case - it can look something like below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH search AS (
  SELECT name, genre FROM
  UNNEST(['Alex','Sarah','James','Robert']) name, 
  UNNEST(['HORROR','COMEDY') genre
)
SELECT name, genre, org FROM (
  SELECT t.name, t.genre, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT t.org LIMIT 20) orgs
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t JOIN search s 
  ON LOWER(s.name) = LOWER(t.name) 
  AND LOWER(s.genre) = LOWER(t.genre) 
  WHERE RAND() < 0.5
  GROUP BY t.name, t.genre
), UNNEST(orgs) org
ORDER BY name, genre, org
```

Of course logic of JOINing is still on you - equality or LIKE or REGEXP, etc

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, I got it to work with my dataset almost perfectly.
When you say the logic of JOINing is on me, do you mean running this once per "org" and joining the data together? I am currently attempting to get both "Data_one" and "Data_two" to display after adding "Data_two org2" to the top select, but am thwarted by "UNNEST(orgs) org". Why is "orgs" pluralised?

Comment: Edit: I see why it's pluralised, the length 20 array is orgs, but I tried adding a second variable to the setup and changed it to: 
UNNEST(orgs) org, UNNEST(orgs2) org2
And I jumped from 60 results to 1200! 
I really appreciate your knowledge here. Will keep trying to work it out.

Comment: By JOIN'ing logic I meant what is in ON clause (`LOWER(s.name) = LOWER(t.name) AND LOWER(s.genre) = LOWER(t.genre)`) as I mentioned this really depends on how you want to identify qualified genres and names  - by equality, by being alike etc.

Comment: if you still will have challenge with data_one, data_two - please post new specific question and we will be happy to answer. Meantime, have in mind it is really depends on your actual table's schema. if , for example, those data_one and dta_two are part of the org record  - you can just use `org.data_one, org.data_two` in you select statement (of course with actual fields names) :o)

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually fine with the schema and JOINs. I have created a new question here which will hopefully explain my new issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49454231/unnesting-multiple-arrays-in-bigquery

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` for this, I think:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name
                                order by (case when Genre like '%HORROR%' then 'HORROR'
                                               when Genre like '%COMEDY%' then 'COMEDY'
                                          end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from `dataset-table`
      where name in ('Alex', 'Sarah', 'James') and
            (genre like '%HORROR%' or genre like '%COMEDY%')
     ) t
where seqnum <= 20;
```

This is not 100% equivalent, because any films classified as "HORROR-COMEDY" will also be treated as "HORROR".  On the other hand, `genre` should not contain multiple values, unless it is a repeated record or JSON.  Storing multiple values in a string is a SQL anti-pattern.